# invokerepeating meathod didn't allow other script to run in unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Two Script is attached with my one scene in unity , in one script i used method **invokerepeating** when it is called , my second script which is attached with the buttons didn't work.

```c#
void Start()
{
    currentImage = 0;
    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (CallChangeImage));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start ();
    }
}

public void CallChangeImage()
{
    InvokeRepeating("ChangeImage", 0.1f, frameRate);
}

private void ChangeImage()
{
    if (currentImage == frames.Length - 1)
    {
        CancelInvoke("ChangeImage");
        Destroy(explosion);
    }
    currentImage += 1;
    explosion.sprite = frames[currentImage];
}
```

when i used this **invokerepeating** in other thread, it gave error this method only invoke in main thread. 
After calling this scene, i didn't go back to any other scene because my all code is going to be stuck.
*Help me solve this problem!!*

Comment: Unity's API is not thread safe, which means in order to use methods inside unity's api you must go through the main thread, for what purpose are you using that thread?

Comment: this code continuous change the picture to make the gif sense

Comment: then you don't need a thread for that, check out the answer below

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct way to do it without the use of threads

```
void Start()
{
    currentImage = 0;
    InvokeRepeating("ChangeImage", 0.1f, frameRate);
}

private void ChangeImage()
{

        if (currentImage == frames.Length - 1)
        {
            CancelInvoke("ChangeImage");
            Destroy(explosion);
        }
        currentImage += 1;
        explosion.sprite = frames[currentImage];

}
```

Comment: i said: this script stuck other script to run . script behind button didnt work